# Vue.js getting null for the json when initially loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning vue.js and trying to call a json file and parse the data. Everything is working but when I refresh the page, I see a blank page before my data is loaded and in console log I get `TypeError: e.myData is null`. After few second the data is displayed on the page.

`main.js`:

```js
new Vue({
    el: `#app`,
    render: h => h(App,{
      props:{
        todoID: this.dataset.id
      }
    })
  })
```

and my `App.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
      <div>{{myData.getName()}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Info from '@/getInfo'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: {
    todoID: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: null,
      myData: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    fetch(`http://localhost/json-end-point/`)
      .then(async response => {
        const data = await response.json();

        if (!response.ok) {
          const error = (data && data.message) || response.statusText;
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        // set the date here, am I doing this right?
        this.myData = new Info(data);
        this.data = data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.errorMessage = error;
        console.error("There was an error!", error);
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

`getInfo.js`

```js
export default class Info {
    constructor(Data) {
      if (Data) {
        const data = JSON.parse(Data);
        console.log(data.name); // returns name
        // console.log(data);   // returns the json data
        this.name = data.name;
      }
    }
    
    getName() {
      return this.name;
    }
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong here `this.myData = new Info(data);` but I am not sure what I can do.

#### Update

I was able to remove the console log by adding `v-if="myData !== null"`. Still not sure assigning data like this `this.myData = new Info(data);` is a good approach. How can I improve this code?

Comment: you can add a v-if in the template to show it if the variable isn't null. right now the page renders before the call is finished

Comment: thanks doing `v-if="myData !== null"` removed the console log. Is doing `this.myData = new Info(data);` a good approach? or I should try another way? I dont want to learn the wrong way.

Comment: using new means you can't return a promise and wait, a better approach would be to wrap the fetching in an async function

Comment: @KareemKamal do you have an example?

Comment: yes, added an answer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to let the template show different states so it doesn't try to render the data before it arrives, but shows a loading indicator instead.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="myData">
      <div>{{ myData.getName() }}</div>
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="isLoading">
    Loading data...
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="errorMessage">
    {{ error.message }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Info from '@/getInfo'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: {
    todoID: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: null,
      myData: null,
      error: null
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getData()
  },

  methods: {
    async getData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/json-end-point/`)

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(data?.message || response.statusText)
        }

        this.data = await response.json();
        this.myData = new Info(this.data);
      } catch (error) {
          this.error = error;
          console.error("There was an error!", error);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: this returns an error `Module build failed, reserved word 'await'` for this line `this.myData = await getData()`

Comment: forgot the `this.` before `getData`, try with it

Comment: thanks, still the same error

Comment: added async to the created hook, sorry I'm too used to the linter doing these for me.

Comment: this worked, but I also get `TypeError: t.myData is undefined` in console log. Even though there is `<div v-if="data">` condition.

Comment: does changing the v-if to be checking myData instead of data fix it?

Comment: I tried that already, it stopped showing anything, the other one shows the info but has that error in console log

Comment: found it! the function returns undefined and we assign undefined to myData in created(), removing the assignment fixes it

Comment: yeah that fixed it :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238294/discussion-between-rain-man-and-kareem-kamal).

Answer (score 0):

You could stick the `myData.getName()` call inside a computed field that either returns the name if `myData != null` or an empty string (or whatever value you want when there is no data available).

Something like this

```
computed: {
    getName() {
        return this.myData ? this.myData.getName() : '';
    }
}
```